# Installing pCloud drive

Tags: software-installation, applications

I'm somewhat new to linux, and I was hoping someone would be able to help. I would like to install pCloud drive, and I followed the instructions on the site [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-and-use-the-pcloud-desktop-client/). However this doesn't seem to work, when I run "sudo ./pcloud" the terminal hangs at the following:

> dks@Phobos:~/Downloads$ sudo ./pcloud
>
> Down: Everything Downloaded| Up: Everything Uploaded, status is SCANNING
>
> Update for linux-x64-prod-v1.7.1 is not available
>
> Down: Everything Downloaded| Up: Everything Uploaded, status is READY
>
> (pcloud:3274): libappindicator-WARNING **: 19:22:30.549: Unable to get the session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”
>
> (pcloud:3274): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 19:22:30.549: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”

I did get the login screen, but upon logging in my pCloud folder was unreadable and it gave me the following popup error
[image]

I attempted to manually uninstall pCloud to try again, but I wasn't successful. Whenever I try to navigate to the pCloud folder via the Files app, the folder won't open. However, whenever I navigate through something else (for example Code), I *can* see the file structure and even open the files.

What's going on? Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: I'm just noticing this, but it may be related to the fact that the pCloud Drive folder has no owner, and I seem to be unable to change the owner via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

After some test in my Elementary OS 5.1 maybe you need have this packages

For the line

> (pcloud:3274): libappindicator-WARNING **: 19:22:30.549: Unable to get
>   the session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for
>   address “disabled:”

```
$ dpkg -s  libappindicator1
Package: libappindicator1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 76
Maintainer: Ubuntu Desktop Team <ubuntu-desktop@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: libappindicator
Version: 12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libdbusmenu-glib4 (>= 0.4.2), libdbusmenu-gtk4 (>= 0.4.2), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.31), libindicator7 (>= 0.4.90)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Suggests: indicator-application (>= 0.2.93)
Description: Application Indicators
 A library and indicator to take menus from applications and place them in
 the panel.
 .
 This package contains shared libraries to be used by applications.
Homepage: https://launchpad.net/libappindicator
```

---

```
$ sudo apt install libappindicator1
```

---

and for the other line

> (pcloud:3274): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 19:22:30.549: Unable to
>   get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for
>   address “disabled:”

```
$ dpkg -s   libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 
Package: libdbusmenu-glib4
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 145
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libdbusmenu
Version: 16.04.1+18.04.20171206-0ubuntu2
Description: library for passing menus over DBus
 libdbusmenu passes a menu structure across DBus so that a program can
 create a menu simply without worrying about how it is displayed on the
 other side of the bus.
 .
 This package contains shared libraries to be used by applications.
Homepage: https://launchpad.net/dbusmenu
Original-Maintainer: The Ayatana Packagers <pkg-ayatana-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

---

```
$ sudo apt install libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64
```

---

Comment: I did do this, but it seemed to not help (as far as I could notice). I eventually noticed that pCloud had mounted the drive with no owner, so after going into bash and forcing a user change, it seems to work and be stable.

Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: what bash script are you talking about because for me PCLOUD it's a binary

Comment: I did not take into account one of the lines It seems that other people have the same problem of the recent update of the kernel, the subject is here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251013

Comment: Basically what happened to me is that pCloud was running, but somehow had mounted the drive with no user (which is why I couldn't access anything). I simply went into root and did chown ... etc. to the mounted directory (not to the binary) After that it seemed to work (and is still working).

Comment: thank you for this clarification